# Persistence in KNOPPIX v7.0.4

Tags: linux, livecd, knoppix

I recently used the KNOPPIX DVD as a tool when re-installing my Windows desktop machine and it worked great so I've been doing some more reading to become familiar with it. I have the "KNOPPIX Hacks" book (2nd edition) by Kyle Rankin from 2007. Its a bit old and appears to cover KNOPPIX v5.1, whereas I'm using the latest, KNOPPIX v7.0.4 so I would expect some differences.

Having said that, he has a good section in the book on persistence. i.e. saving off the contents of /ramdisk and then using them when booting in the future off the disk. In this way you can change system settings and configure it the way you want and take that with you the next time you boot.

The problem is, the commands he describes don't appear to exist in KNOPPIX 7.0.4. He covers the following which I can't find when booting into KNOPPIX v7.0.4.

- K Menu -> KNOPPIX -> Configure -> Save Knoppix configuration
- /usr/sbin/saveconfig
- K Menu -> KNOPPIX -> Configure -> Create a persistent KNOPPIX disk image
- /usr/sbin/knoppix-mkimage

Can anyone advise me regarding the replacement for the above commands? Is there now a different procedure for achieving persistence with a KNOPPIX disc?

Comment: Try searching for the commands: `locate saveconfig`.

Comment: I tried that and it did find saveconfig in another location.  I tried running it though and it just spit out a bunch of info but didn't seem  to do anything as expected from what I read.  There's no man page for it and I couldn't find any documentation for it (other than the book).  I tried locate on knoppix-mkimage and it returned nothing.  I wonder if maybe saveconfig isn't the way you're supposed to get persistence anymore with Knoppix.  So, back to the original question, does anyone know the current correct way to achieve persistence with Knoppix?

Comment: It seems to me like this is covered in the [FAQ](http://knoppix.net/wiki/Category:Hard_drive_Installation).